# How to reattach a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which contains a fragment. The fragment is successfully attached in the `onAttach()` method (checked it). When I then press a button in the fragment I get a NPE on performing `getActivity`. After reading several SO-questions I found out that by fragment has obviously been detached from my activity. But I don't understand the several answeser and even the android docu how to solve this problem :(

My question now is: How can I reattach my fragment to avoid the NPE?

My acitivity:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppFragmentActivity {
  SearchFragment searchfragment;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    searchfragment = new SearchFragment();
  }


  public void ClickBtnSearch(View view) {
    // Send down to fragment
    searchfragment.ClickBtnSearch(view);


  }
}
```

It's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment android:name="de.unibonn.sdb.wissappmobile.fragments.SearchFragment"
              android:id="@+id/search_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0px"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
  }

  @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }   


  public void  ClickBtnSearch(View view) {

    // Read entered ID and then start search
    String enteredString = "";
    int LabeledObjectID = 0;

    // THE FOLLOWING LINE produces NPE in the getActivity !
    TextView txtError = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtError);
    EditText enteredValue = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dfnLabeledObjectID);

    if (!enteredValue.getText().toString().equals("")) {
      enteredString = enteredValue.getText().toString();

      // Acutally we don't need a try/catch to catch a NumberFormatException as the Inputfield is numeric only #
      // and doesn't accept alphanumeric values or floats. 
      try {
        LabeledObjectID = Integer.valueOf(enteredString);

        // TODO Suche starten
        txtError.setText("the entered ID is" + LabeledObjectID);

      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        txtError.setText(R.string.ERR_Please_Enter_a_nonempty_numeric_ID);
      }
    } else {
      txtError.setText(R.string.ERR_Please_Enter_a_nonempty_numeric_ID);
    }       
  }
}
```

and the fragment's XML button definiton:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/dfnLabeledObjectID"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="ClickBtnSearch"
    android:text="@string/BTN_SEARCH"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you didn't attach the fragment to the activity at all.

you need to call something like this :

```
FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
String tag=SearchFragment.getCanonicalName();
SearchFragment fragment=manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
if(fragment==null)
   fragment= new SearchFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
SearchFragment fragment= new SearchFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment,tag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Where do I have to do this? And if I didn't attach the fragment at all, why was a debug call of `getActivity`just after `super.onAttach()`returning `not null`? This is all strange to me as far as I worked with it (since 4 days now)

Comment: after looking again at the code, i've figured out the problem : you have 2 instances of the fragment. one that is from XML, and one via code (using "new") . you need to choose which method you use, and then continue with it. only the fragment from the XML gets attached in your app, so if you want, you can use it instead (use "findFragmentById") .